# Rails 2.3.5 and oauth-plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I started a rails application from scratch, using Rails 2.3.5, and installed `oauth-plugin`. The installation was done by running `script/plugin install git://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin.git`.

Now, when I try to start the server, I get the following errors:

```
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Rails::Railtie (NameError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
from /Users/Pablo/Projects/test.oauth/vendor/plugins/oauth-plugin/lib/oauth-plugin.rb:16
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /Users/Pablo/Projects/test.oauth/vendor/plugins/oauth-plugin/rails/init.rb:1:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /Users/Pablo/Projects/test.oauth/config/environment.rb:9
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from script/server:3
```

I can't figure out why this is failing. Am I missing a dependency? What other information I can provide to others help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [oauth-plugin.gemspec](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/blob/master/oauth-plugin.gemspec) is for Rails 3. Note this line loads version 0.4.4 of the gem:

> s.add_dependency(%q, [">= 0.4.4"])

Try undoing the changes `script/plugin install` did first.

<strike>Then, per the readme on the gem's github page, I would try installing the gem manually:</strike>

> gem install oauth-plugin --pre

Nevermind, I the above and got version 0.4.4, which is again probably for Rails 3.
Try:

> gem install oauth-plugin -v=0.3.11

Then, add to environment.rb:

```
config.gem "oauth"
config.gem "oauth-plugin"
```

Comment: Nate: how can you tell from the gemspec file that it is for Rails 3? Also, how can install oauth-plugin not as a gem but as a plugin inside my rails project?

Comment: @pgb I can't tell only from the gemspec file that it's for Rails 3. I know that 0.4.4 is what you installed since it's in the gemspec file. I also know that version must be for Rails 3 since you are getting a Railtie error. So I went back to 0.3.11 (only 0.3 version available) and looked at the Readme - bingo no Rails 3 info :) As for installing it with `script/plugin` try `script/plugin install git://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin.git -r 0_3-branch`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work around the interweb.

http://www.jamievandyke.com/the-inherited-resources-railties-error

See this if you're not using bundler.

http://anlek.com/2010/03/uninitialized-constant-railsrailtie/

Comment: No luck. I already tried that and didn't change the error I get.

Comment: I would try using another branch, the one you're using is no longer maintained. (pelle) Just out of interest, why you not use rails 3? I was putting off updating an existing app and it wasn't all the difficult upgrade. https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby

Comment: I'll try the other branch. As for using Rails 3, I'm maintaining an existing app, and so far migrating is not an option. I'll see if I can talk them into migrating later.